# Angular: How to use and share entry components such as forms for lazy loading

Tags: angular, forms, lazy-loading

I have converted my app to lazy load routing but I am facing some issues.

I have for example 2 form components that are shared accross the app.

However they crash when the components are not registered on the entryComponents of the app module.

For example:

`shared.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ShadeComponent} from '../components/loading/shade.component';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {PrivacyIconComponent} from '../components/privacy-icon/privacy-icon.component';
import {EventActionsComponent} from '../components/event-actions/event.actions.component';
import {ChartsTimelineComponent} from '../components/charts/timeline/charts.timeline.component';
import {ChartsPieComponent} from '../components/charts/pie/charts.pie.component';
import {ChartsXYComponent} from '../components/charts/xy/charts.xy.component';
import {EventCardChartComponent} from '../components/cards/event/chart/event.card.chart.component';
import {EventFormComponent} from '../components/event-form/event.form.component';
import {ActivityFormComponent} from '../components/activity-form/activity.form.component';
import {DeleteConfirmationComponent} from '../components/delete-confirmation/delete-confirmation.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    ShadeComponent,
    PrivacyIconComponent,
    EventActionsComponent,
    ChartsTimelineComponent,
    ChartsPieComponent,
    ChartsXYComponent,
    EventCardChartComponent,
    EventFormComponent,
    ActivityFormComponent,
    DeleteConfirmationComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EventFormComponent,
    ActivityFormComponent,
    DeleteConfirmationComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    ShadeComponent,
    PrivacyIconComponent,
    EventActionsComponent,
    ChartsTimelineComponent,
    ChartsPieComponent,
    ChartsXYComponent,
    EventCardChartComponent,
    EventFormComponent,
    ActivityFormComponent,
    DeleteConfirmationComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule]

})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

Dependant module :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import {SharedModule} from './shared.module';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {EventRoutingModule} from '../event-routing.module';
import {EventCardComponent} from '../components/cards/event/event.card.component';
import {EventCardMapComponent} from '../components/cards/event/map/event.card.map.component';
import {EventCardStatsComponent} from '../components/cards/event/stats/event.card.stats.component';
import {EventCardLapsComponent} from '../components/cards/event/laps/event.card.laps.component';
import {EventCardToolsComponent} from '../components/cards/event/tools/event.card.tools.component';
import {ActivityIconComponent} from '../components/activity-icon/activity-icon.component';
import {ActivitiesCheckboxesComponent} from '../components/acitvities-checkboxes/activities-checkboxes.component';
import {ActivityActionsComponent} from '../components/activity-actions/activity.actions.component';
import {MapActionsComponent} from '../components/map-actions/map.actions.component';
import {EventCardChartComponent} from '../components/cards/event/chart/event.card.chart.component';
import {EventCardChartActionsComponent} from '../components/cards/event/chart/actions/event.card.chart.actions.component';
import {EventCardDevicesComponent} from '../components/cards/event/devices/event.card.devices.component';
import {ActivityHeaderComponent} from '../components/activity-header/activity-header.component';
import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
import {MatPaginatorIntl} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatPaginatorIntlFireStore} from '../components/event-table/event.table.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    MaterialModule,
    EventRoutingModule,
    AgmCoreModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [
    EventCardComponent,
    EventCardMapComponent,
    EventCardStatsComponent,
    EventCardLapsComponent,
    EventCardToolsComponent,
    EventCardChartActionsComponent,
    EventCardDevicesComponent,
    ActivityIconComponent,
    ActivitiesCheckboxesComponent,
    ActivityActionsComponent,
    ActivityHeaderComponent,
    MapActionsComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [
    {provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: MatPaginatorIntlFireStore},
  ],
})


export class EventModule {
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Template error: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'
```

However, as you can see the shared module does import the ReactForms and Angular Form module.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that you're trying to use a property from `FormsModule` or `ReactiveFormsModule` in a module that has not imported either of them.

I see that you have included them in your `SharedModule` **`exports`** array but you never added them to the **`imports`** array. As far as I know, you can't export things which have not been previously imported or declared. I think adding `FormsModule` and/or `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `SharedModule.imports` would solve the issue.

Comment: I ll give it a try. I had read that if you export 3rd party modules from a shared modules you dont need to import them

Comment: No luck so far :-/

Comment: Actually bingo. 

So this is what was my misconception. When using eg a shared module and you import that to others , if that module does not use / has entry components , then you dont need to import any modules such as react etc. Similar to eg building a material module for sharing.

Comment: I actually didn't know that you could omit the import if it is for 3rd party modules which are only gonna be exported again. Pretty interesting. So basically you need to import the FormsModule in this case, not so much because you want to export it later, but because you're using it in components which belong to the SharedModule.